# How to Save the PDF by Specific name in I.E by inline Property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssrs-2008

I have one requirement: when we save any generated PDF it's taking the name of page, but I want to give the specific name.

I have tried it with code change but this was no help.

In Mozilla it's working fine but in I.E. it's not working.

Anyone who has faced the issue before, please help me.

Code:

```
Dim report As Byte() = ReportSrv.Document_Get(version, reportTemplateID, caseno, User.Identity.Name, UseThisRequestForRest)

Response.ContentType = "application/PDF"
Response.Filter = New System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(Response.Filter,CompressionMode.Compress)

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate")

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename='" + caseno + "'.pdf")

Response.OutputStream.Write(report, 0, report.Length)

Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + caseno + ".pdf");
```

OR

```
string str = new ContentDisposition { FileName = this.FileName, Inline = Inline }.ToString();
Response.AppendHeader( "Content-Disposition", str );
```

Comment: Hi @Jitendra How I will give the file name in 

string str = new ContentDisposition { FileName = this.FileName, Inline = Inline }.ToString();

Comment: like this string str = new ContentDisposition { FileName = "ABC.pdf", Inline = Inline }.ToString();